# Es posible autorreferenciar una lista por comprensión (una sola línea) en python para eliminar elementos repetidos

Tags: python

Eliminar los elementos repetidos en una lista python es posible mediante el siguiente algoritmo:

```
my_list = [ 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3 ]

new_list = []

for element in my_list:
    if element not in new_list:
        new_list.append(element)

print new_list # produce [5, 3, 7, 2]
```

Sin embargo, cuando pretendo realizar algo similar en una lista por comprensión el algoritmo sólo funciona (produciendo la lista original) si se redunda en la declaración de la lista "recipiente".

```
my_list = [ 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3 ]

#new_list = [] #produce la lista original si se incluye esta linea 

new_list = [ element for element in my_list if element not in new_list ]

print new_list
```

Por tanto, mi pregunta es si es posible autorreferenciar una lista por comprensión en python para eliminar elementos repetidos que pueda ser expresada en una sola línea.

Lo más cerca que he podido realizar es lo siguiente:

```
my_list = [ 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3 ]

my_list.sort()

n = len(my_list)

new_list = [ my_list[i] for i in range(n) if my_list[i-1] != my_list[i] ]

if n >= 1 and len(new_list) == 0:
    new_list = [ my_list[0] ] #para capturar excepciones de listas como [1]
                              #o [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

print new_list
```

Sin embargo, requiere que la lista de origen esté ordenada y considerar las posibles excepciones (ver código anterior).

**Nota de Edición:**

La línea siguiente también funciona:

```
new_list = [ my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[i] not in my_list[:i] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no te importa el orden, lo más fácil es usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Un set es una colección sin orden que no permite repetidos, entonces, podés hacer

```
new_list = list(set(my_list))
```

Si te importa el orden, entonces podés usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) para tener un índice que te permita iterar en el rango de `my_list` que ya fue procesado

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in enumerate(my_list) if x[1] not in my_list[:x[0]]]
```

Comment: El código con `enumerate` lo dejaría mejor así: 

    new_list = [x for (i,x) in enumerate(my_list) if x not in my_list[:i]]

Answer (score 2):

Por simplificarlo un poco, podrías crear antes una lista previamente y rellenarla en la *list comprehension* sin necesidad de usar índices o indexaciones:

```
vieja = [1,8,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,7,6,3,2]
nueva = []
[nueva.append(val) for val in vieja if val not in nueva]
```